# Error while deleting a file in C++

Tags: c++, delete-file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>


int main()
{
    int k=0;
    char *source = new char[30];
    char *destination = new char[30];
    while(k==0)
{
    cout<<"Enter the source File location: ";
    cin>>source;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter the destination File location: ";
    cin>>destination;
    ifstream is(source,ios::in | ios::binary);
    ofstream os(destination,ios::out | ios::binary);

    if(is==NULL || os==NULL)
    {
        perror("Either the input or the ouput location is invalid");
        cout<<endl<<"Try again with new location.\n";
        cout<<endl<<"To exit press 7 and to continue press 0";
        cin>>k;

    }
    else
    {

                    os<<is.rdbuf();
        k++;
        cout<<endl<<"File moved successfully";
        cout<<endl<<"Do you want to delete the original file: [y/n]";
        if(getch()=='y')
        {
            if(remove(source)== -1) 
            perror("Error in deleting File");
            else
            cout<<" Source File deleted.";
        }

    }
}
}
```

File is successfully deleted but while deleting the file it says:

> "Error in deleting Files" Permission Denied.

I have used both kind of slashes(forward and back) when it asks for the source and the destination address(like C:/MIT/adi.txt) and I am compiling it using mingw compiler... Is it an OS error or is there any problem with my code or compiler?

Comment: Well, does the program actually have permission? And is 30 chars really enough for a whole path?

Comment: Where do you **close the input stream**?

Comment: You really shouldn't compare a stream with `NULL`.  Just test its status directly: `if ( !is || !os )`.  (Although I'd check each separately, to generate a better error message.)

Comment: And what's with all of the `endl` _before_ outputting.  The convention would be to put it after the line you output, not before.  (In particular, `std::cout` is a text file, and if the last character output is not `'\n'`, it's implementation defined whether it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things jump out at me:

- 30 chars is not enough for most full paths. Also you should not use `new` if you can avoid it; fixed-length arrays can just as well go on the stack; and this is a job for `std::string` if ever there was one.
- You did not close the file before attempting to delete it. Platforms vary on this requirement but I think Windows does not like that. Destroy or close the stream before calling `remove`.

Comment: You want to explicitly close the file first anyway, since you almost certainly want to verify that the copy worked before removing the source.  (Saying `File moved successfully` when it wasn't isn't going to win you any friends in the user community.)